# MSTest not using my projects target framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mstest

I have a simple C# UnitTest project with a single test that targets .net 4.5.2

The test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
  Assert.AreEqual("A © B © C © D ☺ E  F", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("A &copy; B &#169; C &#xA9; D &#x263a; E &#x11111; F"));
}
```

When I run the test in VS2015 everything passes as expected.

The problem is when I run the test using MSTest. The test fails with the output

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<A © B © C © D ☺ E  F>.
>   Actual:<A © B © C © D ☺ E &#x11111; F>.

Based on the Actual output it appears to be using .net 4 which is not the target framework of my project.

I'm running mstest.exe from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe

Am i doing something wrong here or is there a different version of MSTest I should be using?

EDIT: Looking at the MSTest output I think my logic is backwards here. MSTest is correctly failing where Visual Studio is not.

Answer (score 1):

MSTest.exe is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) and should only be used for backwards compatibility for projects from VS2010.

You can run the tests using `VSTest.Console.exe` and you will see the same result that you are seeing in Visual Studio.

`VSTest.console.exe` can be found at:
`%VS140COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`